# React Native Lottie Animation Only Plays On First Tap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lottie

So essentially, I want to play the lottie animation everytime it is tapped. Here is my UI code for the lottie animation:

```
<Pressable onPress={playGame}>

<LottieView
   ref={loseAnimationRef}
   style={styles.egg}
   source={Lost}
   autoPlay={false}
   loop={false}
   onAnimationFinish={() => {
      resetAnimation();
   }}
/>

</Pressable>
```

Here is my state code for the lottie animation:

```
  const loseAnimationRef = useRef(null);

  const playGame = async () => {
    await mainGameLogicUC();
    playAnimation()
  };

  const playAnimation = () => {
      loseAnimationRef.current.play()
  }

  const resetAnimation = () => {
      loseAnimationRef.current.reset()
  }
```

On the first tap, the animation play perfefctly fine. But on all other taps, the animation won't play. I tried pausing the animation in the `onAnimationFinish` and then resuming it, but that also didn't work. Am I missing something?

#### EDIT

I got rid of the `resetAnimation()` in the `onAnimationFinish` and that solved the initial problem. But the thing is, **I want** the animation to be reset to the beginning every time. Why does it break when I reset the animation?

Comment: What is the logic in `mainGameLogicUC`? Maybe it throws an error and `playAnimation` is not called again? You can comment it out and check if it works

Comment: You can also try to reset the animation just before it plays instead of doing it in advance.

Comment: @Marat Just tried it, the problem still persists.

Comment: @Jeremy The reason why I reset the animation is because the first frame of the animation is visible to the user. When the user taps the animation, it runs and then when it is done it should clip back to the first frame. Therefore, the animation needs to be reset before the user taps the animation (and runs `play()`)

Comment: Did you wait for finishing the animation before tapping the second time?

Comment: @Marat Yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming back to this problem a few days later, I found the solution

Playing the lottie animation seems to be considered a side effect, therefore, editing the references to the animations should be done in a `useEffect` hook

The solution that worked for me:

(again, in this code, I  **want**  the animation to reset to the beginning before the user taps the screen screen again.

> state code

```
  const isMounted = useRef(false);

  const [isWonAnimationShowing, setIsWonAnimationShowing] = useState(false);
  const [isAnimationPlaying, setIsAnimationPlaying] = useState(false);
  const loseAnimationRef = useRef(null);
  const winAnimationRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      if (isAnimationPlaying) {
        _playAnimation();
      } else {
        _resetAnimation();
      }
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true;
    }
  }, [isAnimationPlaying]);


  const playAnimation = () => {
    setIsAnimationPlaying(true);
  };


  const _playAnimation = () => {
    if (isWonAnimationShowing) {
      winAnimationRef.current.play();
    } else {
      loseAnimationRef.current.play();
    }
  };


  const resetAnimation = () => {
    setIsAnimationPlaying(false);
  };


  const _resetAnimation = () => {
    if (isWonAnimationShowing) {
      winAnimationRef.current.reset();
    } else {
      loseAnimationRef.current.reset();
    }
  };
```

> UI code

```
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <Pressable disabled={isAnimationPlaying} onPress={playGame}>
        {isWonAnimationShowing ? (
          <LottieView
            ref={winAnimationRef}
            style={styles.egg}
            source={Won}
            autoPlay={false}
            loop={false}
            onAnimationFinish={() => {
              resetAnimation();
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <LottieView
            ref={loseAnimationRef}
            style={styles.egg}
            source={Lost}
            autoPlay={false}
            loop={false}
            onAnimationFinish={() => {
              resetAnimation();
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Pressable>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
const animationRef = useRef<AnimatedLottieView>()
const isAnimating = useRef<boolean>(false)

const onAnimationPress = () => {
    if (!isAnimating.current) {
        isAnimating.current = true
        animationRef.current.play()
    }
}

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onAnimationPress}>
    <AnimatedLottieView
        source={source}
        ref={animationRef}
        autoPlay={false}
        loop={false}
        onAnimationFinish={() => {
            isAnimating.current = false
            animationRef.current.reset()
        }}
    />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```